# Reading specific data from multiple files in Tcl

Tags: regex, file-io, scripting, tcl

I am writing a TCL script to read multiple files and search them for a line containing certain word using regexp. I have been able to search for one thing from the files. But I need to modify the script to search for multiple things in a script print the items found in one file together in one line, then the items found from another file in 2nd line.
I have written this

```
foreach fileName [glob  /home/kartik/tclprac/*/*] {
#   puts " Directories present are: [file tail $fileName]" 
    set fp [open $fileName "r"]
    while { [gets $fp data]>=0 } {
    if {[regexp {set Date*} $data] | [regexp {set Channel* } $data] } {
    #puts "file: [file dirname $fileName] data: $data"
    set information "file: [file dirname $fileName] data: $data"
    puts $information
    set fp2 [open output.txt "a"]
    puts $fp2 $information

}
}
}
```

Now i am getting output as:

```
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_3 data: set Date 02/08/2021 
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_2 data: set Date 01/08/2021
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_1 data: set Channel Disney 
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_1 data: set Date 31/07/2021
```

what i want is something like

```
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_3 data: set Date 02/08/2021 
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_2 data: set Date 01/08/2021 
file: /home/kartik/tclprac/wire_1 data: set Date 31/07/2021 set Channel Disney
```

Comment: Note that `|` is the mathematical "or". Use `||` for the boolean "or".

Comment: The key will be to not print the information immediately: build up a list of  matched lines, then print out the joined list when you've finished reading the file.

Comment: Also, close your open file handles, or you might run out of them.

Comment: Also, you only need to open output.txt once, before the foreach loop starts

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to gather the results for a single file onto a single line, rather than printing out a line for each matching line (the traditional `grep` tool approach) with the per-line results being separated by spaces.

We can do this, but it gets a bit clearer if we split the code up into a couple of procedures (one for processing the contents of a single file, the other for the whole job).

```
proc processFileContents {name contents accumulatorChannel} {
    set interesting [lmap line [split $contents "\n"] {
        if {![regexp {set (?:Date|Channel) } $line]} {
            # SKIP non-matching lines
            continue
        }
        # Trim the matching lines
        string trim $line
    }]
    # If we matched anything, print out
    if {[llength $interesting]} {
        set information "file: $name data: [join $interesting \n]"
        puts $information 
        puts $accumulatorChannel $information
    }
}

proc processFilesInDir {pattern accumulatorChannel} {
    foreach fileName [glob -nocomplain -type f $pattern] {
        set channel [open $fileName]
        set contents [read $channel]
        close $channel

        processFileContents $fileName $contents $accumulatorChannel
    }
}

set accum [open output.txt "a"]
processFilesInDir /home/kartik/tclprac/*/* $accum
close $accum
```

If you're using an older version of Tcl that doesn't have `lmap` (8.5 or before) then you can write that with `foreach` (as `lmap` is really just a collecting form of `foreach`; the only difference is that `lmap` uses a hidden temporary variable to do the accumulating):

```
proc processFileContents {name contents accumulatorChannel} {
    set interesting {}
    foreach line [split $contents "\n"] {
        if {![regexp {set (?:Date|Channel) } $line]} {
            # SKIP non-matching lines
            continue
        }
        # Trim the matching lines
        lappend interesting [string trim $line]
    }
    # If we matched anything, print out
    if {[llength $interesting]} {
        set information "file: $name data: [join $interesting \n]"
        puts $information 
        puts $accumulatorChannel $information
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you ask, no, you can't access `lmap`'s hidden temporary from Tcl code. It lives in either C or bytecode space only (depending on how the Tcl code has been compiled, not an important thing here) and literally has no name that your Tcl code can see.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain this part  `if {![regexp {set (?:Date|Channel) } $line]} {
            # SKIP non-matching lines
            continue
        }
        # Trim the matching lines
        string trim $line`